# Standard User account not getting removed on El capitan

Tags: macos, user-account

I am not able to delete user account on El capitan . The Minus (remove option ) is inactive here . I tried doing this by logging in to admin account . 
Please help!!!!

Comment: I assume that you 'unlocked' the settings in the preference panel... if so, and if you are trying to delete the *only account* on the machine in question, try: - add a new account, with admin privileges. - now try remove the account you want to remove. See if that works. BTW, I think you will need at least 1 account with admin powers at all times.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

It's possible that the user you're attempting to remove is the last FireVault capable account. You can see this illustrated by launching Directory Utility (/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory Utility.app) from the command line and attempting to remove the user:

[image]

From the command line, you should get something along these lines:

`2017-11-06 16:08:03.777 Directory Utility[866:19875] Couldn't delete record "demouser" of type "dsRecTypeStandard:Users": Error Domain=com.apple.OpenDirectory Code=4001 "Attempting to delete the last FileVault capable user" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Attempting to delete the last FileVault capable user, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges.}`

No matter how you launch Directory Utility or which permissions you use, you'll be unable to delete the user.

### Solution

You'll need to [enable FireVault if it isn't already](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837) and **add the user you want to the list of users capable of unlocking the disk:**

[image]

You can also use the command line: `sudo fdesetup add -usertoadd username`

After this is done, you'll be able to delete the user. You can also turn off FireVault if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar need to delete a local account after binding the computer to Active Directory. We accomplished this by running these commands while logged in with a network account that was granted admin.

```
sudo dscl . delete /Users/<username>
sudo rm -rf /Users/<username>
```