# Remove user account under OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos

I would like to remove a user account under El Capitan by following [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18890?locale=en_US) recipe:

1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Users & Groups.
2. Click the lock icon to unlock it, then enter an administrator name and password.
3. Select the user you want to delete, then click Remove below the list of users.
4. ...

What happens is that I cannot select the to-be-deleted user at this point (I can only select the current account plus "Guest User"). What could be wrong. (And yes, I am using an account with administrator privileges.)

Comment: Probably similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210853/standard-user-account-not-getting-removed-on-el-capitan?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the user you want to delete is actually logged out. You can't force delete a currently logged in user.

Answer (score -2):

Once you select the user to be deleted,at the bottom hit the minus sign, from there you will be directed on how you wish to delete the user and any files associated with the user....

Comment: Nope, this won't work.